# HoneyComb layout question

Tags: android, layout, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am not completely new to android development but I am new to the 3.0 android honeycomb.

My problem is that I can't find how to set the layout to anything bigger then the standard small layout. It does not matter wether I set the width's fill_parent, wrap_content or match_parent...

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need this in your Manifest file. Obviously you don't need all the entries, I only have to include the android:largeScreens="true" to get the full size.

```
  <supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: Better is to just say android:targetSdkVersion="11" (or greater in the future).  This tells the platform that your app has been tested against that version of the platform, so it can turn off *all* compatibility code for older applications.  Some of the things this impacts are described in the docs for the various API levels: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html

Comment: @hackbod - That's a good trick. I was under the (false) impression that the targetSdk required the application to be loaded by a device with that sdk(version) or better.

Comment: That's the behavior of android:minSdkVersion. You can use both at once.